# If $T$ is an invertible linear transformation and $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$, then $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

I saw there is a proof for invertible matrices, but I don't know how to put this mathematically for a transformation.
How do I prove an invertible linear transformation has the same eigenvectors as its inverse?

Comment: Can't you just fix bases and consider your linear transformation as a matrix?

Comment: yup...I suppose that's what should have been done in the first place. I have posted an algebraic solution.

Comment: Wouldn’t the proof be exactly the same as the one for matrices?

Answer (score 4):

Observe that for an invertible matrix $A$ with eigenvector $\mathbf v$ and corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda\neq 0$, you have that 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf v &= I \mathbf v\\&=A^{-1}A \mathbf v\\&=\lambda A^{-1} \mathbf v
\end{align*}
Hence $A^{-1} \mathbf v = \lambda^{-1}\mathbf v$

Answer (score 1):

OK, so Iv'e found a solution!

\begin{align*}\\
Tv &= \lambda v  \ \ \vert *T^{-1}  \\
T^{-1}Tv &= T^{-1}\lambda v  \\
v &= \lambda T^{-1}v  \ \ \vert  *\lambda^{-1}   &  \text{(Invertible transformation, $\lambda\neq 0$)}  \\
\lambda^{-1}v &= T^{-1}v 
\end{align*}

For $T^{-1}$, eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$, eigenvector is $v$ (same as eigenvector of $T$).

Hope this helps!